# How I make approximation for a large 5, numbers C# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How I make approximation for a large 5, numbers C# code
example

```
62     I want to get 65 
63     get   65
71.15  get  75
```

Comment: would 77 be 80? Would 66 be 70?

Comment: Obtain the digits first. Use ```n % 10``` to obtain the first (right-moist) digit. The, ```n/10``` will return the other digits plus a reminder. Eliminate the reminder with the equivalent in C# for ```Math.floor```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round a number to the next HIGHEST 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679697/round-a-number-to-the-next-highest-10)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Math.Round(x - x % 5) + 5
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0WjV9U)

Comment: @WeatherVane understand your concert but since it is 5 should not be a problem...

Comment: I was thinking of the `71.15` but also of C (tag was removed).

Comment: @WeatherVane, I added rounding to the nearest integer

Comment: Yes, but the input `71.15` is a floating point number, and in C at least, `x % 5` is a syntax error for `float x` or `double x`. One would use `fmod`.

Answer (score 1):

- Divide by 5.
- Find the ceiling.
- Multiply by 5.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
double num = 64.65;
double nextMultiplyOf5 = (int)(num + 4) / 5 * 5;
```